# How to fetch daily data from monthly data using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

My data is as follows:

```
table name : dailysale

column
date       payment
2015-12-01 320
2015-12-01 430
2015-12-01 435
2015-12-02 456
2015-12-02 555
2015-12-03 120
```

It's just a 6 column data, list is too big like 400 to 500 data every day.
now I want to calculate total payment on the daily basis using MySQL query.

Comment: Using PHP `date()`  you can create your date filter which can be used as filters in `WHERE` clause of `SELECT` query.

Comment: Even `strtodate()` can be useful to convert to dates like `strtodate('yesterday')` will give you your date

Answer (score 1):

```
 select sum(payment) as totalPayment, date from table_name group by date;
```

This will sum up payments based on each date. It will show you the total summation of payment for everyday in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
   SELECT date, SUM(payment) FROM dailysale
   GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Already accepted but my reputation is < 15. It will be visible to you when my reputation will reach > 15.